# How to format a Datatables table to display a bool as a checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable

I'm working on a project in c#/ASP .net/Datatables, and am running into an issue when trying to display a boolean the way I want to. Currently it's coming up as "true" or "false", when I'd prefer it to display as either a checked or empty box. It sounds like datatables should be able to handle this but the example code they show doesn't match the syntax we're using in the rest of the project. What we have is:

```
<th data-data="ProjectName">Project Name</th>
<th data-data="OwnerName">Owner Name</th>
<th data-data="ReferenceNumber">Reference Number</th>
```

followed by

```
<th data-data="IsTaxExempt">Tax Exempt</th>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it a clickable check box or just to display data?

Comment: If your using ajax you can use the "render" option for that column

Comment: I'm aiming to just display data

Comment: How have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this take a look at the columns.render option from the Datatables.net documentation, I think the examples [from the Datatables.net website can get you going in the right direction](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). You probably would have to setup some options in the initialization of the table as :

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
      "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 3, //Targets would be the 0 based index of the column
             "data": 'IsTaxExempt',
             "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ){
                       return data ? '<input type="checkbox" disabled checked/>' : <input type="checkbox" disabled/>'
             }
       } ]
 });
```